# Config Swagger-ui with Jersey

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to configuring `Swagger + Swagger-ui + Jersey`. I have my web service on **Tomcat**.

I have been able to integrate the swagger with Jersey.

To integrate `swagger-ui`, based on the `swagger-ui documentation`, I need to put the files under `/dist/` in my webapp directory and changing the `index.html` file to point to my `swagger.json`. However, I want to use `swagger-ui webjar` found here

> https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/swagger-ui/2.2.6

I have not been able to figure out how to do this.

Comment: probably add it to your dependencies in pom.xml of the maven project. what else have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use this same dependency on my project and didn't find a solution to change it. What I did is:

1) Create a "doc" folder inside my "webapp" folder on my project

2) [Download](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/releases) Swagger-ui zip file

3) Extract dist folder and copy all files to my "webapp/doc" folder

4) Change index.html that was in "webapp/doc"

It might help you.