# How do I use Swagger with Jersey in Spring?

Tags: jersey, swagger-ui

I am trying to use Swagger (2.6) with Jersey (1.5) in SpringBoot (1.5.8)

My calls to my public API work fine http://localhost:57116/rest/customer/list

When I load up the http://localhost:57116/swagger-ui.html site, it displays Swagger with a lot of default APIs, but it does not display my API.
[image]

I tried following this [Config Swagger-ui with Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40914184/config-swagger-ui-with-jersey) but it still does not come back.

This is my JerseyConfig

```
@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

public JerseyConfig()
{
    register(CustomerImpl.class);
    configureSwagger();
}
public void configureSwagger()
{
    this.register(ApiListingResource.class);
    this.register(SwaggerSerializers.class);
    BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
    beanConfig.setTitle("Swagger sample app");
    beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.0");
    beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
    beanConfig.setHost("localhost:57116");
    beanConfig.setBasePath("/rest");
    beanConfig.setResourcePackage("com.mypackage");
    beanConfig.setScan(true);
}
}
```

This is my application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableSwagger2
public class CustomerApplication {...}
```

This is my endpoint

```
@Component
@Path("customer")
@Api(value = "Customer API")
public class CustomerImpl {
    @Path("list")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation(value = "list")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = List.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Failure")})
    public String[] getList()
    {
        return new String[]{"IBM", "Microsoft", "Victor"};
    }
}
```

When I try a similar config using Spring RestController, it works fine, but with Jersey I don't see my public API. It seems to be ignoring my Swagger configuration

Answer (score 6):

Are you using `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey` dependency or `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web` in your `pom.xml`?

It also seems you are using the Swagger bean generated by `SpringFox` and not by your `BeanConfig`.

In order for Swagger to work, you should rely on `spring-boot-starter-jersey` and remove all SpringFox dependencies including `@EnableSwagger2` annotation.

The `swagger.json` in a Jersey application is generated by the `io.swagger:swagger-jersey2-jaxrs` library. As for the Swagger UI, you can use [vanilla Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) static resources.

You may also need to change the  **resource package** in your **BeanConfig** to your application base package. Currently, you have:

```
beanConfig.setResourcePackage("io.swagger.resources");
```

Here is a working [example](https://github.com/indrabasak/spring-jersey-swagger-example) with Spring Boot, Jersey, and Swagger.
In this example, the resource package is set to the application base package:

```
beanConfig.setResourcePackage("com.basaki");
```

Comment: How are you trying to run and what type of errors are you getting?

Comment: When I remove the springfox dependencies and @EnableSwagger2, I get the following dialog box every time I do anything:Unable to infer base url. This is common when using dynamic servlet registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway. The base url is the root of where all the swagger resources are served. For e.g. if the api is available at http://example.org/api/v2/api-docs then the base url is http://example.org/api/. Please enter the location manually: